# Audio Equalizer for YouTube Music app

Tags: audio, youtube, equalizer

I want to adjust music played by YouTube Music app (don't mix up with Google Play Music).
How can I do it?

Built-in MusicFX equalizer doesn't affect YouTube Music. I also tried several external apps, which claim that they are OS wide, and in fact they're able to adjust sounds from standard Music app and Play Music app. But none of them work for YouTube Music app. They only can change volume while it's playing.

If you suggest app-based solutions, please, don't suggest apps that you haven't tried yourselves so they worked for you. If there's a solution with features shipping with Android itself, all the better.

Comment: If your device is rooted V4a and Dolby both work

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic) for details). For where your question might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](//android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) and [Where to ask for app recommendations?](//android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575). I've adjusted your question accordingly so it doesn't get in danger of being put on hold as off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I use Viper4Android and it works for me on YouTube (Have been using it since ICS era). It requires root though.

Installation method various depending on your Android version.
If your device is supported by Magisk, I recommend you to use the Magisk Manager and install the Viper4Android module through it. 
Official way is to install using the app [Official XDA thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2191223) (You'll probably need to set Selinux mode to permissive to let it install drivers which I personally don't recommend, so go for the Magisk way)

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer and include a link where to find Viper4Android?